# How to show custom post type count in the users admin page

Tags: custom-post-types, users

There's a post count in the user page of the WordPress admin area. I have a custom post type events. Is there some hook I can use to add my event count to the post count, or else to add a column for the event count?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 2 pretty undocumented hooks `'manage_users_custom_column'` and `'manage_users_columns'` that you can use for the scope.

They works in same manner of `'manage_posts_custom_column'` and `'manage_posts_columns'` that are better documented, see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_posts_columns).

So you can do something like this:

```
/*
 * Add Event Column 
 */
function users_events_column( $cols ) {
  $cols['user_events'] = 'Events';   
  return $cols;
}

/*
 * Print Event Column Value  
 */ 
function user_events_column_value( $value, $column_name, $id ) {
  if( $column_name == 'user_events' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $count = (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
      "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE 
       post_type = 'events' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_author = %d",
       $id
    ) );
    return $count;
  }
}

add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'user_events_column_value', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'users_events_column' );
```

only be sure to use the correct post type slug in the SQL query inside `user_events_column_value` funcion

Comment: thats a nice answer, but it does not provide the link to edit page, on the count item

Answer (score 4):

here's an improvment to @gmazzap's answer, including links to post list:

```
/*
 * Add Location (business) Column to user screen
 */
function bayadaim_users_location_column( $cols ) {
  $cols['user_locations'] = 'YOUR_COLUMN_NAME';  
  return $cols;
}

/*
 * Print Event Column Value  
 */ 
function bayadaim_users_location_column_value( $value, $column_name, $id ) {
  if( $column_name == 'user_locations' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $count = (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
      "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE 
       post_type = 'YOUR_POST_TYPE' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_author = %d",
       $id
    ) );
    $link = '<a href="' . admin_url() . 'edit.php?post_type=location' . '&author=' . $id . '" title="Posts location">' . $count . '</a>';

    $return = ($count > 0) ? $link : $count;

    return $return;
  }
}

add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'bayadaim_users_location_column_value', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'bayadaim_users_location_column' );
```